# How can I add spinner to checkbox array

Tags: java, android, arrays, checkbox, spinner

How can I add spinner to checkbox array, when check the checkbox the spinner will active then when select from spinner it will show the result in textView and changes if change the spinner selection changes
if I write

```
selection.add(txt + "Body Towels");
```

It just show (1Body Towels) and never change if I select another number

this is my method code

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //spinners for string array numbers 1-5
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bbodytowelssp);
        spinner.setEnabled(false);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (HouseKeeping.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray
                        (R.array.numbers));
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

             txt = adapter.getItem(position).toString();//selected spinner

         }

          @Override
           public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

          }
        });

        //for checkbox
        // I want to add spinners here and added to selection like example (2 Body Towels)

        boolean checked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.bbodytowelscb:
                if (checked) {
                    spinner.setEnabled(true);//first spinner 
                    selection.add("Body Towels");

                } else {
                    selection.remove("Body Towels");
                    result.setText("");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.bbodylotioncb:
                if (checked) {
                    selection.add("Body Lotion");
                } else {
                    selection.remove("Body Lotion");
                    result.setText("");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.bbrushcb:
                if (checked) {
                    selection.add("Brush");
                } else {
                    selection.remove("Brush");
                    result.setText("");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.bconditionercb:
                if (checked) {
                    selection.add("Conditioner");
                } else {
                    selection.remove("Conditioner");
                    result.setText("");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.bhandtowelscb:
                if (checked) {
                    selection.add("Hand Towels");
                } else {
                    selection.remove("Hand Towels");
                    result.setText("");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.bshampoocb:
                if (checked) {
                    selection.add("Shampoo");
                } else {
                    selection.remove("Shampoo");
                    result.setText("");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.bshowergelcb:
                if (checked) {
                    selection.add("Shower Gel");
                } else {
                    selection.remove("Shower Gel");
                    result.setText("");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btoothsetscb:
                if (checked) {
                    selection.add("Tooth Sets");
                } else {
                    selection.remove("Tooth Sets");
                    result.setText("");
                }
                break;
        }

        String final_selection = "";
        for (String s : selection) {
            final_selection = final_selection + s + "  "; //show checkbox result
            result.setText(final_selection); //the textView
            result.setEnabled(true);    

        }
    }
```